# how to sort and filter the higchart left axies table (gantt chart)

Tags: angular, highcharts, gantt-chart, highcharttable

Here is the link of table along with gantt chart, I need if user click on the column header Est.Days a dropdown should come with the value less than 0 , between 0 to 5 and greater than 5. user can select any of the filter. Also i need a sorting arrow on each column, so user can sort the table, once any action happened to the table the chart should get changed.
https://www.highcharts.com/demo/gantt/left-axis-table/brand-dark

Comment: Hi, I check out the Gantt doc: https://www.highcharts.com/docs/gantt/getting-started-gantt. It includes information about grouping tasks.  Also, here is a demo you can base on: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/xdw39btm/.
Please note that the Gantt chart doesn't inherently support the type of filtering you're looking for right out of the box, so it will require some customization. Have you had a chance to try implementing this yet? If so, please share your code.While I can assist you with the Highcharts configuration, please note that custom implementations are beyond my standard support scope.